# Finding vectors in the Span of v1 and v2

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

```
Let v1=(2,−2,1) and v2=(2,−1,1).

Select all vectors below in the span of v1 and v2.

The answer choices are 
A. (0,−1,0) 
B. (0,0,0)
C. (2,−3,1)
D. (1,−3,0)
```

I couldn't understand how to solve this problem and which method to use. Can someone help me with this.
I used the code filter to make it more understandable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with determinants?

Comment: I'm not, but as long as I can get the answer I can research for the formulas or anything to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will check answer A. and let you check the others:

Asking whether $(0,-1,0)$ is spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is basically this question:

is there a solution to $(0,-1,0)=a(2,-2,1)+b(2,-1,1)$?

$2a+2b=0, -2a-b=-1, a+b=0$.  The solution is $a=1, b=-1$.

(Let me know if you need help obtaining that solution.)

I.e.,  $(0,-1,0)=1(2,-2,1)-1(2,-1,1)$, so $(0,-1,0)$ *is* in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

---

Alternative solution using determinants:

$\begin{vmatrix}2&2&0\\-2&-1&-1\\1&1&0\end{vmatrix}=0,$

so $(2,-2,1), (2,-1,1)$ and $(0,-1,0)$ are linearly dependent;

i.e., $(0,-1,0)$ is in the span of $(2,-2,1)$ and $(2,-1,1)$.

Comment: So, if three of them are linearly dependent is it going to be in the span of the (2,-2,1) and (2,-1,1)? I checked the others answer choices and only the last choice in linearly independent so I'm guessing the answers are A, B, and C

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct.  (B was a "give-away")